# OpenGL shader language; how to specify precision for vec4?

Tags: qt, opengl-es, shader, glsles

I'm writing a Qt OpenGL application, just starting out with GLSL, and am trying to compile a "simple" fragment shader I found in an example on the web:

```c
#version 320 es
out vec4 fColor;

void main()
{
    fColor = vec4 (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

But when trying to add this shader from source, I get this error message from Qt's `addShaderFromSourceFile()`:

> QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment):
>   0:3(12): warning: extension `GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions` unsupported in fragment shader
>   0:1(1): error: No precision specified in this scope for type `vec4`

What is the proper syntax to declare a precision for type `vec4`?
I cannot seem to find an example of how to to this for `vec4`, and trying things like this:

```
precision mediump vec4;
```

...results in a syntax error.

Note that I want the shader to run on an embedded system, hence the "`#version 320 es`" line at the beginning.

Answer (score 6):

`vec4` is not a vaild type for a default precision qualifier.
The type in default Precision Qualifiers has to be either `int`, `float` or any opaque type (e.g. a sampler is a opaque type).

The precision statement

```c
precision mediump float;
```

affects all floating points (e.g. `float`, `vec2`, `vec3`, `vec4`, `mat3`, ...)

A precision qualifier can also be set to single variable:

```c
out mediump vec4 fColor;
```

this will *overwrite* the default precision qualifier.

For details see [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.20 Specification - 4.7. Precision and Precision Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.20.html#precision-and-precision-qualifiers).